# package level collection

Tags: go

I have a globally defined map on a package level.
When ever i refer to it, it seems has though the map is recreated on every usage.

1) Is that a correct assumption ?

2) What's the reasoning behind it ? (I'm guessing immutability and thread safety)

3) How would a globally used collection be defined in GO to be used by all packages (i.e. Think of a Global static definition in languages like C#) ?

The package :

```
package device

import "strconv"

var Devices =  map[int]Device { 1 :Device{ name : "Lamp" }, 
                    2: Device{ name : "AirConditioner"} }

type Device struct{
    name string
    Value int
    State int
}

func (d *Device) String() string  {
    return d.name + "," + strconv.Itoa(d.Value) + "," + strconv.Itoa(d.State)
}
```

Usage :

```
import d "hello/app/device"

func main() {  

    device := d.Devices[1]
    device.State = 1

    // device after change ->  Lamp,0,1
    fmt.Println("Device After Change -> " + device.String())

    deviceAgain := d.Devices[1]
    // using the device again prints default values -> Lamp,0,0
    fmt.Printf(deviceAgain.String())
 }
```

Comment: When you copy `d.Devices[1]` to `device`, you are copying the value, which is type `Device`. Any modifications you make happen to the copy. You can change this by (a) changing your map to type `map[int]*Device`, or (b) copying the changed value back to the map after modifying it.

Comment: Also don't forget about concurrent use: if this map is to be accessed from multiple goroutines, you have to synchronize those accesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to declare your global variable using pointer variables

```
var Devices =  map[int]*Device {
    1 :{ name : "Lamp" },
    2: { name : "AirConditioner" },
}
```

To make it safe for concurrent reads and writes, one way is to declare a new struct and add a lock

```
type Devices struct {
    sync.Mutex
    data map[int]*Device
}

func (d *Devices) Get(i int) *Device {
    d.Lock()
    defer d.Unlock()
    return d.data[i]
}

func (d *Devices) SetState(i int, s int) {
    d.Lock()
    defer d.Unlock()
    d.data[i].State = s
}
```